# Read Big text online using python

Tags: python, streaming, text-processing

I have to read a text file of 50 GB. I have to do some processing with that file. I cannot download the text file as I am doing the processing on a remote server. Is it possible using Python to stream the content of the file using its URL and read it line by line ?

Comment: What protocol do you use to access the online file? ftp? http? If it is http or https, then you can use `urllib2.urlopen()` to get a file-like object and iterate through it, line by line. I have tried it with http/https, but not ftp, it could work.

Comment: have a look : https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html or https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html and https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html

Comment: i'm using http, so urlilib2 will not open the entire file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the simplest way is :

```
import urllib2  # the lib that handles the url stuff

data = urllib2.urlopen(target_url) # it's a file like object and works just like a file
for line in data: # files are iterable
    print line
```

You could even shorten it to

```
import urllib2

for line in urllib2.urlopen(target_url):
    print line
```

But remember in Python, readability matters.

However, this is the simplest way but not the safe way because most of the time with network programming, you don't know if the amount of data to expect will be respected. So you'd generally better read a fixed and reasonable amount of data, something you know to be enough for the data you expect but will prevent your script from been flooded :

```
import urllib2

data = urllib2.urlopen(target_url).read(20000) # read only 20 000 chars
data = data.split("\n") # then split it into lines

for line in data:
    print line
```

> In python 3 and up use [urllib.request](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html) instead of urllib2

Answer (score 1):

You can do with `urllib2`,

`urlopen` will work as like files and files are iterators yielding 1 line at a time until there are no more lines to yield.

```
import urllib2
for line in urllib2.urlopen("http://www.myhost.com/SomeFile.txt"):
    print line
```